# Changing the label colour in editing a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am looking for a way to change the label colour when editing a cell. The default color is white and that's shown when I swipe to delete but I would like to change it to say Black the same way the Apple News app does it as shown in the images below.

This is the usual swipe to edit code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {



        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Rename") { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void in



        }

        editAction.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black
        return [editAction]



    }
```

This is the default color. 
[image]

This is how apple news does it. 
[image]

Any ideas. I am using swift 3 but anything in swift or even ObjC will be cool. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this by using `UITableViewRowAction`. Apple does not allow us customise the button like we do use in `UIButton` in `UITableViewRowAction`.

I have an idea, let me know whether it will solve your problem. Let's say that Apple has an image which has these three icons in it `Love`, `Share` & `Save` [ From the above image in the question ].

What you can do is that, you can set the backgroundColor of `UITableViewRowAction` instance by using the `UIColor` `patternImage` method.

So it will look something like this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let discussion = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "") { _, _ in
        }

        discussion.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Love&Share&SaveIconsInOneImage"))

        return [discussion]
    }
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I am going to give it a shot this weekend and get back to you. ;)